# Successfully integrated Cordova 5.0.0 push plugin.I want to get the payload of notification message when user clicks the notification

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am mobile application developer.am working on adding  Cordova push kit plugin in my Cordova project .First I added 5.0.0 Cordova push plugin but in that version am not able get payload of notification message when we receive notification no event is triggered so we not able to handle notification messages .Then Huawei developer team advised me to use latest 5.0.2 Cordova plugin version which is  added with event listener features. But in latest plugin u used androidx but our project we using Android so getting some conflicts while adding latest.Same time our manager don't want to migrate androidx in our project.So pls help me to solve this issue.My need is want to handle some event whole receiving notification message and also while clicking notification Message and also I need payload of that notification message.pls help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Please migrate to AndroidX.
 Go to android folder in root directory of Cordova Project.
 Create a new file named gradle.properties. You don't need to create this file if you have it
 Open gradle.properties file and add these lines to in.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

From above,  you will be able to migrate from android to androidx.
Or , 
If CP uses cordova-android 9.0.0 version then AndroidX support needs to enabled through config.xml. To do this just add following line below to config.xml ->
Note : Please migrate from android to androidx , not only for Push Kit , in future many kits if your CP wants to integrate there also in updated version with more functionalities androidx required.